# Linux compile error: undefined reference to `kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable'

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to call function kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable() in tick-sched.c, but got the following error:

```
/usr/src/linux-3.13.9/kernel/time/tick-sched.c:213: undefined reference to `kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable'
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just find definition of this function in kernel and use:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable)
```

I hope it help.

Comment: I mean I did this before and got the error which I post here: /usr/src/linux-3.13.9/kernel/time/tick-sched.c:213: undefined reference to `kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable'

Comment: In which file have you added it? Have you recompiled the kernel with this modification?

Comment: I add EXPORT_SYMBOL(kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable); to arch/x86/kvm/x86.c and recompile the kernel, then got above error

Comment: it's weird and I search for hours, but cannot figure it out

Comment: Did you use #include <linux/kvm_host.h> ?

Comment: yes, also put extern int kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable(struct kvm_vcpu *vcpu); in tick-sched.c

Comment: cat  /proc/kallsyms |grep kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable give me:

Comment: `ffffffffa03a1d24 r __kstrtab_kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable [kvm]
ffffffffa038fa78 r __kcrctab_kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable [kvm]
ffffffffa038f280 r __ksymtab_kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable [kvm]
ffffffffa0366a30 t kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable [kvm]`

Comment: If I see correctly then - kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable is not exported properly because there is "t" but should be "T".

Comment: yes 't' means cannot be called from other file, but I don't know where is the problem

Comment: I've just recompiled the kernel with those changes and I have no such error. Try "make clean" and "make" in linux source directory.

Comment: I run make clean and make, it remain the same -.-

Comment: whats your output of cat /proc/kallsyms |grep kvm_arch_vcpu_runnable ?